# SSL Error while trying docker for windows 10

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, docker-build

I own a coporate laptop and I was trying to diligently the tutorial on the docker build. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app

When i tried that I started getting error on the certificates. Has someone faced similar kind of erros and do anyone of you know how to fix this for windows 10 laptops

[image: docker screen for ssl error]

Comment: I guess that either your environment has removed the root certificate that pypi.python.org is using, or you have a proxy set up that intercepts all traffic and your browsers are set up to work with in whereas HTTPS connections from Python are not. Can you go to pypi.python.org in a browser? Can you open an HTTPS connection to other servers from Python? Can you get more information about the certificate validation error? (Also if you're locked down to this degree I'd guess your IT department wouldn't want you running VMs from your laptop either, so Docker is probably out.)

Comment: Hi there, I tried to open pypi.python.org in broswer and the web page loads up and also yes i am able to load other https web pages.